# Regretting counter offer acceptance

Tags: job-offer

I recently decided to accept a counter-offer and subsequently declined an accepted offer.  A day after I made this decision, I realized what I had done and that I had already mentally checked out of where I currently work, and I am feeling immense regret, especially as the other offer had a more promising future.  From this experience alone, I don't think I'll ever take a counter offer again...Live and learn.

Now my question is, would it be possible in any way to salvage the offer I had reneged?  I do have a unique skillset that is hard to find that they are interested in.  I'm wondering if its worth a shot a week after this poor decision...or perhaps I should give it a shot in a couple months?  Fully understanding that I might not get anything back.

Answer (score 4):

There's always a chance.   Reach out ASAP to your contact at the other company that you turned down.   Just tell them you have had more time to consider your options and you'd like to accept it if they haven't moved on to the next candidate.

Be aware they have very possibly already offered it to the #2 candidate.

Comment: That's pretty much the only thing to do.  Don't wait.  While its very possible that the offered it to the #2 candidate, you never know.

Comment: Be aware that they may also think "wow, this candidate is pretty indecisive/unreliable in their decision making!"

Comment: Yes, that is my conundrum.  If I reach out ASAP, I feel like they would get an impression that I am incredibly indecisive (and admittedly, I was being so).  Thus, I am wondering if its better to reach out in a couple months, hoping the position is left intact.  I have some hopes that it will be, since they rarely hire people into the team as a senior, but I was qualified through the interview process to be brought onboard as a senior.  I also already know the company's product inside and out having worked on it at other places.

Comment: So phrase it in the standpoint of "I really had a chance to think about it, and have decided to accept the offer".    Personally, I think they'll move on from you and they'll likely sour on you the longer you wait...but I, of course, was not part of the interview process.    Only you can really tell what the vibe was and if they'll drop you and move on.